# Is there an Emacs mode for OpenOffice.org package files?

Tags: emacs, openoffice.org

Is there an Emacs mode for OpenOffice.org (compressed) package files? For instance, is there one that could decompress each of the included XML files, and open each of them in its own buffer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've written a python library for Impress (using emacs).  Since odf files are really just .zip files, the following was extremely useful in my .emacs:

```
;; Use archive mode to open Python eggs
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.egg\\'" . archive-mode))
;; and OOo files
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.odp\\'" . archive-mode))
(add-to-list 'auto-mode-alist '("\\.otp\\'" . archive-mode))
```

I should add that when you edit (and save) a file in the zip file using archive mode, it zips it back up, speeding up debugging....